# Vuex store updating all instances, I only want current instance updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm building a simple blog page where users can like and dislike comments. My current issue is whenever user hits "addLike", or "subtractLike" methods all the comment likes are being updated not just the current one being clicked.

store:

```
export const state = () => ({
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      likes: 0,
      name: 'amyrobson',
      img: '/img/avatars/image-amyrobson.png',
      post: `Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved.
              But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the
              responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.`,
    },
  ],
})

export const mutations = {
  pushComment(state, comment) {
    state.comments.push(comment)
  },
  addLikes(state) {
    state.comments.forEach((element) => element.likes++)
  },
  subtractLikes(state) {
    state.comments.forEach((element) => element.likes--)
  },
}
```

component:

```
 <button @click="addLike">
        <img src="/img/icon-plus.svg" />
      </button>

      <p class="py-3 text-primaryBlue">{{ comment.likes }}</p>

      <button
        @click="subtractLike">
        <img src="/img/icon-minus.svg" />
      </button>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      reply: false,
    }
  },
  },
  methods: {
    addLike() {
      this.$store.commit('comments/addLikes')
    },
    subtractLike() {
      this.$store.commit('comments/subtractLikes')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You apply a forEach function on the comments array in store in both methods ... you need to pass the comment you're liking/unliking and affect only that record.

Comment: @TremendusApps would you apply this logic inside the store? or the component itself? I tried passing in vuex but am receiving "undefined". I know it must be something simple I am overlooking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you're incrementing the likes for *all* comments regardless of their IDs. In order to increment the link for a *specific* comment, you need to pass some kind of identifier that will identify your comment. That identifier should be unique: in this case let's assume that the `id` field is unique.

Then, in your component you will need to commit the mutation with this bit of information (the identifier):

```
<button @click="addLike(comment.id)">
  <img src="/img/icon-plus.svg" />
</button>

<p class="py-3 text-primaryBlue">{{ comment.likes }}</p>

<button @click="subtractLike(comment.id)">
  <img src="/img/icon-minus.svg" />
</button>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      reply: false,
    }
  },
  },
  methods: {
    addLike(id) {
      this.$store.commit('comments/addLikes', id)
    },
    subtractLike(id) {
      this.$store.commit('comments/subtractLikes', id)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Then you will need to update your commit definition to include that identifier. Use that identifier to find the comment whose `like` property you want to increment/decrement:

```
addLikes(state, id) {
  const foundComment = state.comments.find(comment => comment.id === id);
  if (foundComment) foundCommment.likes++;
},
subtractLikes(state, id) {
  const foundComment = state.comments.find(comment => comment.id === id);
  if (foundComment) foundCommment.likes--;
},
```

p/s: Remember that objects in your array is *by reference*, so `foundComment` is simply a reference to the original comment object in `state.comments`, which allows you to mutate it directly.